# Error when running a unix 'at' job

Tags: unix, while-loop, at-job

The code is:

```
at -k $wval <<ENDMARKER

while [[ -s Usr_List ]]; do
    for i in $(cat Usr_List); do
        if finger -m | grep $i; then
            echo "$i is online" | elm $mval
            sed "/$i/d" <Usr_List >tmplist
            mv tmplist Usr_List
        fi
     done
done

ENDMARKER
```

Looking at the actual at job, it is

```
while [[ -s Usr_List ]]; do
    for i in jim
joe 
tim; do
        if finger -m |grep ; then
            echo " is online" | elm jack
            sed "//d" <Usr_List >tmplist
            mv tmplist Usr_List
        fi
     done
done
```

jim joe and tim are the names on the list Usr_List

It seems like the cat Usr_List and the $i are the problem but I am not sure how to fix this.

Thanks

EDIT:
The at job sends an email saying that jim was unexpected.

Comment: For one thing, you're not passing `$i` to `finger`. For another, you haven't given us a clue *what the problem is*.

Comment: I added a small edit. When the script runs, I get an email describing the output of the at job and it says 'jim unexpected'.

Answer (score 0):

Check `man at`, in particular the part about ".... executed at a later time, using /bin/sh.". The script you are showing is valid `bash`, but depending on what `/bin/sh` is on your system, may not be valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

## What's Happening

The problem is that the lines in your here-doc are being expanded when you input the at command.  That means that the shell expands `$(cat Usr_List)` into:

```
jim
joe
tim
```

And it expands `$i` into the empty string, because it is not yet defined.

## What You Want to Happen

You really want those variables to be expanded when the `at` command fires, not when you're telling the `at` command what to do.

## How to fix it

In order to keep the shell from expanding variables in a here-doc, you can simply quote your delimiter at the beginning.  So, change your first line:

```
at -k $wval <<ENDMARKER
```

to

```
at -k $wval <<"ENDMARKER"
```

and it will work great.

### Incidentally,

I'm curious, as my `at` command doesn't have a `-k` option--what is that supposed to do?